# Is there any way to make Visual Studio auto-import necessary namespaces when implementing an interface?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

When I tell Visual Studio to auto-implement an interface, it "helpfully" tries to resolve any unreferenced namespaces - by prefixing every class in those namespaces with the namespace name! Is there any way to make it just import the namespaces with a using statement up top, instead of cluttering the method and property declarations with repetitive namespace noise?

Comment: This totally gives me the irrates too

Comment: What about `Ctrl+.`? Admittedly you have to do it one by one. Otherwise you need R#.

Comment: @HighCore the interface gets implemented correctly, but with full namespace (e.g. `void Foo(Bar.Baz.Qux qux)`, where OP wants `Qux` in the signature and `using Bar.Baz;` on top.

Comment: please accept the answer if you are satisfied with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). 
It does importing when you paste and it warns you and suggests when you can import namespaces.
It also shows unused ones.

Here is an example:

[image: Resharper namespace import]

Comment: Sorry for edit, other pic also didn't show what OP mentioned. :-P

Comment: Hmm, I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Express, so that wont' work, but thanks anyway!

Comment: Also, does this actually work for when interfaces are being autoimplemented?

Comment: yes it does, see if you can get a paid version of VS + some plugins. it's amazing what it can do. :)

Comment: Yep, I actually have VS2010 Pro and an old version of Resharper, but I prefer working in VS2012 Express for the most part!